# SQL Server - Minimize JSON output

Tags: sql-server, json, stored-procedures

I've got a SQL Server stored procedure where I do a lookup for a couple of standard/static values, then generate a table of comparison values (1 per person/record).

Basically, the stored procedure outputs the following "static" values:

- Minimum
- Maximum
- LowThreshold
- HighThreshold

Those 4 values are the same for every output record, but can change based on the parameters provide into the stored procedure. That is, those values are only "static" for a single execution of the stored procedure.

The stored procedure also outputs the following "dynamic" values:

- Name
- Score

Those 2 values are different for every output record.

Pulling all of these values into a table, a normal `For JSON` output from SQL Server would give me something like this:

```
{
  "Scores":[
    {
      "Min" :   0,
      "Max" : 100,
      "Low" :  40,
      "High":  70
      "Name": "Bruce Banner",
      "Score": 82 
    },
    {
      "Min" :   0,
      "Max" : 100,
      "Low" :  40,
      "High":  70
      "Name": "The Incredible Hulk",
      "Score": 99
    },
    // And so on...
  ]
}
```

What I'd like to have is some way to minimize bandwidth and raw procedure output size by having the JSON output structured something like this:

```
{
  "Criteria":{
    "Min" :   0,
    "Max" : 100,
    "Low" :  40,
    "High":  70
  },
  "Scores":[
    { "Name": "Bruce Banner", "Score": 82 },
    { "Name": "The Hulk"    , "Score": 99 },
    // And so on...
  ]
}
```

I can figure out how to get just the `Scores` object using a query something like this:

```
Select
    Name,
    Score
From
    Table
Order By
    Name
For JSON PATH, ROOT('Scores');
```

So, that basically gives me a JSON object that looks like this:

```
{
  "Scores": [
    { "Name": "Bruce Banner", "Score": 82 },
    { "Name": "The Hulk"    , "Score": 99 },
    // And so on...
  ]
}
```

I can't figure out a way to get that object and add (inject?) the `Criteria` object into it.